# Why can't I connect a register to an output in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, fpga

I am trying to teach myself FPGA's using a Nexsys 2 design lab (Spartan 3E 1200 FPGA) and Xilinx 12.4. I've been able to get most basic functions to work, but I can't seem to modify a register in an `always` block then assign an output to it. Here is my stripped-down code for a blinking LED.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
`define MHZ 33000

module VerilogFirst(
    input clk,
    output led5
);
   reg myout = 1'b0;
   reg[0:8] timer = 8'b00000000;
   always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (timer >= `MHZ) begin
            myout <= ~myout;
            timer <= 0;
        end
        else begin          
            myout <= myout;
            timer <= timer + 1;
        end
   end
   assign led5 = myout;
endmodule
```

And the UCF:

```
NET "clk"   LOC = "B8";# Bank = 0, Pin name = IP_L13P_0/GCLK8, Type = GCLK, Sch name = GCLK0
NET "led5"  LOC = "P15";# Bank = 1, Pin name = IO, Type = I/O, Sch name = LD4? s3e500 only
```

Everything works fine, but when I try to generate the bitstream, I get an error stating that the LED isn't connected to anything.

```
ERROR:PhysDesignRules:368 - The signal <led5_OBUF> is incomplete. The signal is not driven by any source pin in the design.   

ERROR:PhysDesignRules:10 - The network <led5_OBUF> is completely unrouted.

ERROR:Bitgen:25 - DRC detected 2 errors and 1 warnings.  Please see the previously displayed individual error or warning messages for more details.
```

Answer (score 3):

The constant `MHZ` of 33000 won't fit into 9-bit register `timer`.

So `timer` can never exceed that value, `myout` will never flip. The timer value is also never used, because its value can't affect anything, so the compiler will optimize away everything, entirely. Even `clk` signal will be left unused, and you will get a warning about that.

Comment: That gave me an idea to change the register to 32 bits (nothing changed). But using `8b'0100` in the `if` statement worked.

Comment: My mistake. I forgot to increase the register size properly. It works fine now, thanks!